# Releasing memory of a ListView on Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-memory

I've got a ListView with a custom adapter that extends an ArrayAdapter. Each item in the ListView is an ImageView.

The ListView is a menu that is mostly hidden, but is loaded on startup - it takes a HUDE amount of memory.

I'd like it to populate only when it is shown, and to be released when it is hidden (which will hinder performance, but release memory I guess).

How can this be done? Any other ideas to make ListView use the memory better?

Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html. use a viewholder for smooth scrolling and performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Raghunandan said about `ViewHolder` , you should implement the same. That will save from creating uncessary objects and will make your `ListView` scrolling smooth. 
Here is a link which will give you performance tips for your `ListView` http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/